# Migrating versions of SonarQube and cannot find replaced FindBugs equivalents

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

We're upgrading our version of SonarQube to 5.1.2, and see that we're now on a version that no longer ships with FindBugs. It appears that there should be equivalent rules available, but we're battling to find them, especially the ones dealing with database resources that are not closed.

Is there a way of finding which rules replaced these rules?

> Bad practice - Method may fail to close database resource
>
> Bad practice - Method may fail to close database resource on exception
>
> Bad practice - Method may fail to close stream
>
> Bad practice - Method may fail to close stream on exception
>
> Bad practice - Non-serializable value stored into instance field of a serializable class
>
> Dodgy - Transient field of class that isn't Serializable.
>
> Method may fail to clean up stream or resource on checked exception
>
> Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found them - they appear to all be covered by the following two rules that are included with SonarQube.

> Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable
>
> Resources should be closed